# Struggling to make contact form work (HTML5/PHP)

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

I'm having some difficulty getting my contact form working on my website. Whenever I try submit, it opens index.php, a blank page, rather than actually executing the script and firing off an email.

Here's the form.

```
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="message">Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4"></textarea>
        </div>
        <ul class="actions">
            <li><input type="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

Here's the index.php file I'm using.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Test'; 
$to = 'brett@edge.yt'; 
$subject = 'Hello';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
  if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
  } else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
  }
}
?>
```

PHP is seemingly properly installed on my server, I can use a `PHPInfo()` file no problem.

Comment: in HTML in input, you have type="submit" twice. Second one should be name="submit". This way you do not have $_POST['submit'] set, and never getting in the condition.

Comment: Thank you, fixed that and now I'm actually getting somewhere. Unfortunately I'm receiving `Something went wrong, go back and try again` every time, so I must have made an error somewhere else too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email will never try to send because `$_POST['submit']` is not set. You don't have a control on your form named `submit`. If you intended that to be the submit button, you need to give it a `name` attribute.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
```

Then, in your PHP script, check that submit `isset` rather than just evaluating it as a boolean.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ...
```

That way, if the form hasn't been submitted you won't get an undefined index notice.

Comment: Oh well spotted. I changed `type="submit"` to `name="submit"` and the form now runs, but it fails each time. Think there's something else wrong too.

Comment: You mean, you get the 'Something went wrong' message?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to test out the form now. It does run thanks to the previous fix, but now I'm receiving the 'Something went wrong' message.

Comment: Do you have [error reporting enabled,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) and are you seeing any errors?

Comment: In the error log, I've found a huge number of the same error:

`[Tue Aug 30 18:10:28.433915 2016] [:error] .../public/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat`

There is also an occasional

`sh: /usr/sbin/sendmail: No such file or directory`

Comment: Follow up: Managed to fix the issue. Uninstall and reinstall of sendmail did the trick.

Thanks for your help.